# Is there a way to turn off the creation of a temp table during ALTER TABLE?

Tags: mysql, optimization

Is there a way to perform ALTER TABLE in MySQL, telling the server to skip creating a backup of the table first? I have a backup of the table already and I'm doing some tests on it (adding indexes), so I don't care if the table gets corrupted in the process. I'll just restore it from the backup. But what I do care about is for the ALTER TABLE to finish quickly, so I can see the test results.

Given that I have a big MyISAM table (700 GB) it really isn't an option to wait for couple of hours so that MySQL can first finish creating a backup of the original table, before actually adding an index to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only [supported by InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-index-operations), but not MyISAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not doing a backup; it is building the new version.  (The existing table serves as a backup in case of a crash.)

With InnoDB, there are many flavors of `ALTER TABLE` -- some of which take essentially zero time, regardless of the size of the table.  MyISAM (mostly) does the brute force way:  Create an empty table with the new schema; copy all the data and build all the indexes; swap tables.  For some alters, InnoDB must also do the brute force way:  Example changing the `PRIMARY KEY`.